# Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) on mac using filezilla

Tags: macos, sftp, filezilla, ssh-keys, private-key

first I'll point out that I do not have much experience using SFTP to connect to a server and using public and private keys. So please, answer assuming that I know nothing about what you're talking about.

Two things to know about my issue: 1) I've brought on to a project via an agency whose client is overseas. The client is using an overseas host. I have no idea what this host is, and I have no communication with the communication. Communication has to go through the agency, client, and their IT and then back before it gets to me. 2) I was initially able to log in just fine several weeks ago using an FTP client via my Android phone. But we had the client's IT department to create a duplicate testing site for me to code in. Once that was completed, I was never able to connect again.

Ok so, the issue is that whenever I try to connect to their server using their private key and login information that was sent to me I get the following error: Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) Error: Could not connect to server

I'm using a Mac computer and FileZilla. I've tried other FTP clients as well, with no luck. I've also tried using my Android phone with no luck. The client's IT department says that are they able to connect just fine using the information.

That's as much information that I have off of the top of my head. I appreciate any and all help with this issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It can only be answered by the IT department (which will have to be contacted through the agency).

Comment: I'm mainly trying to find out if there is something on my end that's tripping things up. Like I pointed out 1) I was initially able to connect fine several weeks ago. 2) Their IT department says they can connect using the info. I'd like to check around with knowledgeable people before going back to them because communication and cooperation take forever dealing with them. So please hold off on trying to close my topic as someone else may be able to point me in the right direction on the matter.

Comment: Apologies. I missed the bit about the IT department being able to connect just fine. I've retracted my close vote.